# Retreive data from two tables of the same structure

Tags: performance, optimization, sqlite, query-performance

I have a SQLite database where I fetch data from two tables with the following query.

```
select ie.* 
from (select * 
      from History where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from 
      union all 
      select * 
      from Pending where Station = @station and TimeStampCome <= @till and TimeStampCome >= @from
     ) ie 
order by TimeStampCome desc LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
```

Is this the best and most efficient way? I have stored alarm objects in the database. So there can easily be more than 1 million entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer-level ORDER BY will probably cause the entire combined row set to be sorted – at least to the extent that will enable the server to find the last 100 `TimeStampCome` entries starting from the penultimate one. Sorting a million entries cannot be cheap, of course.

I would try reducing the combined set by applying a LIMIT to each leg of the UNION ALL query. Note that an ORDER BY cannot be applied directly to an individual SELECT that is a UNION leg. You will have to use more nesting – either a derived table or a CTE – to apply the ORDER BY and then select from that derived table/CTE. Here is a derived table solution:

```
SELECT
  ie.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          History
        WHERE
          Station = @station
          AND TimeStampCome <= @till
          AND TimeStampCome >= @from
        ORDER BY
          TimeStampCome DESC
          LIMIT 101
      ) AS s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          Pending
        WHERE
          Station = @station
          AND TimeStampCome <= @till
          AND TimeStampCome >= @from
        ORDER BY
          TimeStampCome DESC
          LIMIT 101
      ) AS s
  ) AS ie
ORDER BY
  TimeStampCome DESC
  LIMIT 100
  OFFSET 1
;
```

And this is a variation that uses CTEs, if you are using a SQLite version that supports [Common Table Expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH
  HistoryFiltered AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      History
    WHERE
      Station = @station
      AND TimeStampCome <= @till
      AND TimeStampCome >= @from
    ORDER BY
      TimeStampCome DESC
      LIMIT 101
  ),
  PendingFiltered AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Pending
    WHERE
      Station = @station
      AND TimeStampCome <= @till
      AND TimeStampCome >= @from
    ORDER BY
      TimeStampCome DESC
      LIMIT 101
  )
SELECT
  ie.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM HistoryFiltered
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM PendingFiltered
  ) AS ie
ORDER BY
  TimeStampCome DESC
  LIMIT 100
  OFFSET 1
;
```

Each individual SELECT is using `LIMIT 101` rather than `LIMIT 100`, because at first it is unknown which of them will end up having the latest `TimeStampCome` entry that will be omitted by the outer `OFFSET 1`. Therefore, each source row set must provide as much data as necessary for the ultimate SELECT.